# objective-c: Set dynamic properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a function, that recieves an object, a name of a property and its value. 
Could i set the property of the object with something simple like this:

```
-(void)dynamicSetterWithProperty:(NSString*)propertyThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime
                        andValue:(NSString*)valueThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime{

       _myObject.propertyNameThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime = valueNameThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime;

}
```

Or do I have to do it in this ugly way:

```
-(void)dynamicSetterWithProperty:(NSString*)propertyThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime
                        andValue:(NSString*)valueThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime{

       if([propertyNameThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime isEqualToString@"name"]){
              _myObject.name = valueNameThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime;
       }

       else if([propertyNameThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime isEqualToString@"age"]){
              _myObject.age = valueNameThatIsKnownOnlyInRuntime;
       }

}
```

Comment: @KurtRevis This what I get for setValue:forKey [<QuestionDetails 0x10210b710> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 1759. האם אוטובוס

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can utilize [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1):

```
[_myObject setValue:runtimeValue forKey:runtimeProperty];
```

of course you could check first if the property is valid with `respondsToSelector` or catch any invalid messages by overriding `valueForUndefinedKey:` and `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` in your subclass.

Comment: Technically, you can't in the general case use `respondsToSelector:` to tell whether an object is KVC-compliant for a key, because accessors don't need to follow a set scheme with declared properties. I think it's usually best just to go ahead and let the operation fail naturally unless there is some strong local reason to prevent it.

Comment: This is what I get: [<QuestionDetails 0x10210b710> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 1759. האם אוטובוס

Comment: Well this means that `QuestionDetails` doesn't have a `1759` property. @Chuck True, thanks for pointing that out.